# Projected generic specialization in Java 9 or later, vs List<int>: how will .remove() work?

Tags: java, generics, project-valhalla

Generic specialization along with value types are a projected feature of future JVMs; link to the Valhalla project page [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/).

Now, from what I understand, it would then become possible to declare a:

```
final List<int> myList = new ArrayList<>(); // for instance
```

But then `List` defines another `.remove()` method in addition to the one defined in the `Collection` interface, which takes an `int` as an argument which is the index in the list to remove; that is why, currently, the content of `list` in the example below:

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.remove(2);
```

will be `[1, 2]` and not `[1, 3]` (the most specific overload is chosen).

However, if in the future we are able to declare a `List<int>`, we have a problem: what overload of the `remove` method will be chosen?

Comment: this is not planned for Java 9, maybe Java 10 or later

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I'm aware; which is why I said in the subject "Java 9 or later".

Comment: @fge I am just eliminating a possibility :) they will never make it to 9

Comment: Maybe `remove(2)` simply won't compile, and they'll add a `removeAt` method to `List`?

Comment: @PaulBoddington that would go against the philosophy of Java as a language as I understand it; nowadays you can still compile code written in Java 1.0 using the Java 8 compiler and I don't see it changing anytime soon...

Comment: It wouldn't go against anything. I'm only talking about `remove(2);` not compiling for a `List<int>`, not a `List` of reference type. Since there's no such thing as a `List<int>` at present that doesn't break backwards compatibility.

Comment: @PaulBoddington good point...

Comment: Even the owner of this feature, Brian Goetz, has not answered this, see the bullet points of Open Questions on here: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218, specifically the 8th point, Reference-primitive overloadings

Comment: @fge `you can still compile code written in Java 1.0 using the Java 8 compiler` - while generally true, [there are corner cases](https://ideone.com/WW4NhP). New keywords break backwards compatibility. [Java does it sparingly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), but they do.

Comment: I think the tag should be changed to java-10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer is based on [this paper](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/specialization.html) by Brian Goetz, dated December 2014. This is the latest I could find on the subject; note however that the paper is an "informal sketch" so there's nothing definitive yet regarding your question.

First, a `List<int>` would not be a subtype of `List<Integer>` ([Subtyping](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/specialization.html#subtyping)):

> Initially, it might also seem sensible that `Box<int>` could be a subtype of raw `Box`. But, given our translation strategy, the `Box` class cannot be a superclass of whatever class represents `Box<int>`, as then `Box<int>` would have a field `t` of type `Object`, whereas `t` should be of type `int`. So `Box<int>` cannot be a subtype of raw `Box`. (And for the same reason, `Box<int>` cannot be a subtype of `Box<Integer>`.)
>
> ...
>
> Since generics are invariant, it is not surprising that `List<int>` is not a subtype of `List<Integer>`. The slightly surprising thing here is that a specialized type cannot interoperate with its raw counterpart. However, this is not an unreasonable restriction; not only are raw types discouraged (having been introduced solely for the purpose of supporting the gradual migration from non-generic code to generic code), but it is still possible to write fully generic code using generic methods -- see "Generic Methods".

This paper also lists "Migration challenges", and [reference-primitive overloadings](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/specialization.html#reference-primitive-overloadings) (the problem is your question) is one of them:

> Some overloadings that are valid today would become problematic under specialization. For example, these methods would have a problem if specialized with `T=int`:
>
> ```
> public void remove(int position);
> public void remove(T element);
> ```
>
> Such overloads would be problematic both on the specialization side (what methods to generate) and on the overload selection side (which method to invoke.)

A proposed solution is refered to as [the "peeling" technique](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/specialization.html#the-peeling-technique):

> Consider the overload pair in a List-like class:
>
> ```
> interface ListLike<T> {
>     public void remove(int position);
>     public void remove(T element);
> }
> ```
>
> Existing uses of `ListLike` will all involve reference instantiations, since those are the only instantiations currently allowed in a pre-specialization world. Note that while compatibility requires that reference instantiations have both of these methods, it requires nothing of non-reference instantiations (since none currently exist.)
>
> The intuition behind peeling is to observe that, while we're used to thinking of the existing `ListLike` as the generic type, that it might really be the union of a type that is generic across all instantiations, and a type that is generic across only reference instantations.
>
> If we were writing this class from scratch in a post-specialization world, we might have written it as:
>
> ```
> interface ListLike<any T> {
>     void removeByIndex(int position);
>     void removeByValue(T element);
> }
> ```
>
> But, such a change now would not be either source-compatible or binary-compatible. However, peeling allows us to add these methods to the generic layer, and implement them in a reference-specific layer, without requiring them in the specializations, restoring compatibility:
>
> ```
> interface ListLike<any T> {
>     // New methods added to the generic layer
>     void removeByValue(T element);
>     void removeByIndex(int pos);
>
>     layer<ref T> {
>         // Abstract methods that exist only in the ref layer
>         void remove(int pos);
>         void remove(T element);
>
>         // Default implementations of the new generic methods
>         default void removeByIndex(int pos) { remove(pos); }
>         default void removeByValue(T t) { remove(t); }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now, reference instantiations have `remove(T)`, and `remove(int)` (as well as the new methods `removeByIndex` and `removeByValue`), ensuring compatibility, and specializations have the nonproblematic overloads of `removeByValue(T)` and `removeByIndex(int)`. Existing implementations of `ListLike` would continue to compile since the new methods have a default implementation for reference specializations (which simply bridges to the existing remove methods). For value instantiations, `removeByIndex` and `removeByValue` are seen as abstract and must be provided, but remove does not exist at all.
>
> This technique also enables the "implementation by parts" technique; it is possible to declare a method abstract in the generic layer and provide concrete implementations in both the value and reference layers. If we allowed layers for `T=int`, it would also enable the "specializing the specializations" technique.

With this technique, backward compatibility would be kept and the new methods `removeByValue` and `removeByIndex` would be used.